# how to add a folder (which name has a 'dot' inside) to rails javascript or stylesheet manifest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, fullpage.js

Trying to add 'fullpage.js' (bower component & folder name) to Rails manifest 'application.js' but fail with the 'dot'. I know it can be workaround by changing the folder name to 'fullpage' manually but it will cause problem when deploy to heroku. Is there a way to make 'require_tree' accept folder name with 'dot'?

```
// require_tree .
//
//= require_tree ./"fullpage.js"
```

Comment: What happens if you do `//= require_tree ./fullpage.js`?

Comment: it will raise an error say 'require_tree' need a directory instead of a file.

Comment: Why not just rename the directory?